# Framework7 and Material Design: Styling not rendered

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, html-framework-7

I'm building my first Android app using Framework7. However, when I use the example provided in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/framework7/navbar_basic.htm, and use the CDNs corresponding to the latest version of Framework7 (3.6.0 instead of 1.4.2), my webpage just renders as HTML without any styling whatsoever.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="with-statusbar-overlay">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <title>Notifications</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/3.6.0/css/framework7.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="views">
         <div class="view view-main">
            <div class="pages navbar-fixed">
               <div data-page="home" class="page">
                  <div class="navbar">
                     <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="center">Notifications</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="page-content">
                     <div class="content-block">
                        <p><a href="#" class="button button-raised notification-single">Single-line notification</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="button button-raised notification-multi">Multi-line notification</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="button button-raised notification-custom">With custom button</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="button button-raised notification-callback">With callback on close</a></p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/3.6.0/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happen since you are not init app, also you dont set an App Wrapper, lets check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/c7mLwvp8/)

You can find here app init for F7:

```
var app = new Framework7({
  // App root element
  root: '#app',
  // App Name
  name: 'My App',
  // App id
  id: 'com.myapp.test',
  // Enable swipe panel
  panel: {
    swipe: 'left',
  },
  // Add default routes
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/about/',
      url: 'about.html',
    },
  ],
  // ... other parameters
});
```

App Html Layout:

```
<div id="app">
<div class="views">
         <div class="view view-main">
            <div class="pages navbar-fixed">
               <div data-page="home" class="page">
                  <div class="navbar">
                     <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="center">Notifications</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="page-content">
                     <div class="content-block">
                        <p><a href="#" class="button button-raised notification-single">Single-line notification</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="button button-raised notification-multi">Multi-line notification</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="button button-raised notification-custom">With custom button</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="button button-raised notification-callback">With callback on close</a></p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Note: I suggest you start from [here](https://framework7.io/docs/introduction.html) nested of toutrialpoint website.

Ref:

[Init F7 App](https://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html)

[App Layout](https://framework7.io/docs/app-layout.html)